# redirect print to log files, in subprocesses too

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I am using the following code to redirect my print statements into a text file.

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
log_file = open("message.log","w")
sys.stdout = log_file
print "this will be written to message.log"

subprocess.call("iPython.exe", "script.py") #subprocesses here take this form

sys.stdout = old_stdout
log_file.close()
```

My problem is that this does not seem to apply to subprocesses. The print statements in "script.py" will not appear in "message.log". How can I make it so that they do?

Comment: There is a specific library for logging that may be a better option - https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.call`, which allows you to redirect `stdout` and `stderr`.

```
import subprocess

with (open('message_stdout.log', 'w'), open('message_stderr.log', 'w')) as (stdout_file, stderr_file):
    my_process = subprocess.Popen(["iPython.exe", "script.py"],
                                   stdout=stdout_file,
                                   stderr=stderr_file)
```

You can also redirect stderr to stdout like this, so that all output from `script.py` is sent to a single file.

```
import subprocess

with open('message.log', 'w') as stdout_file:
    my_process = subprocess.Popen(["iPython.exe", "script.py"],
                                   stdout=stdout_file,
                                   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

However, subprocessing something which just calls `iPython` to load another script is an awful way to work. Instead, you should just call the `script.py` modules directly.